# Applying the same update on each item in a list that contains 1-level nested dictionary items

Tags: python, json

I have a list that contains dictionary objects:

```
a = [{'name':'myname', cat:{id:1, link:'xyz'}}, {...}]
```

What I want to do is to extract the `id` inside `cat`, and assign it to `cat` itself, and repeat this for all dictionary items in the list:

```
a = [{'name':'myname', new_cat:1}, {...}]
```

I know I can do this using `for loop`:

```
new_a=[]
for item in a:
    x = {'name':item['name'], new_cat:item['cat']['id']}
    new_a.append(x)
```

I just wanted to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this. For example, would using comprehension list work better for this?

Comment: It doesn't look like a correct Python syntax. Is it a json string or a python object? IS it a list or a dict?

Comment: Your expected output is ambiguous. What happens to `'id'` inside the `dict` value for the `'cat'` key?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the `cat` dictionary becomes a variable holding the value of the `id`.

Comment: You say that you can do this using a for-loop. I doubt a comprehension would be more efficient,  but why don't you just show us what you mean?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga does the update make sense? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a = [{"name": item["name"], "cat": item["cat"]["id"]} for item in a]`

Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks. I receive this error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: @renakre Please give an simple but complete example. I just suppose your data is like `a = [{'name':'myname', 'cat':{'id':1, 'link':'xyz'}}, {...}]`. But what do you really mean about `cat`, `id`, `link`? Are they variables or strings?

Comment: does my update make sense? a['name'] returns its value perfectly, but when I use it inside a loop, I receive `TypeError: string indices must be integers` error.

Comment: @renakre It doesn't make sense. Let's see, `a` is absolutely a `list`. So what does `a['name']` mean? Further, if your for-loop implementation works well, that means `cat` is a variable but also a string as `cat:item['cat']['id']` shows you use variable `cat` as a key of `x` dict but access to `item` dict key by string `"cat"`

Comment: yes `a` is absolutely a list, double-checked. For example, I can use `a[0]['name']` which will return the value of `myname`. But, then when I try to assign it to a variable, I receive the error: `for item in a: myVal = item['name']` whereas this works perfectly: `for item in a: print item['name']` any ideas?

Comment: I don't think error was caused by this line. Maybe it was caused by `new_cat:item['cat']['id']`.

Comment: your post answers my original question. thanks :) I asked this error in another question.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) (although it's not really any more readable (or any faster) than the list-comp):

```
a = [{'name':'myname', 'cat':{'id':1, 'link':'xyz'}},{'name':'yourname', 'cat':{'id':2, 'link':'abc'}}]

a = map(lambda x: {'name':x['name'],'new_cat':x['cat']['id']}, a)
print a

>>> [{'name': 'myname', 'new_cat': 1}, {'name': 'yourname', 'new_cat': 2}]
```